# Can Textfield be a Stateful widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield, stateless, stateful

I have a text field(stateless widget) and a set of radio buttons(Stateful widget). This text field displays different data, depending on the item selected in the radio button.

In such a case, the property of the text field is changing. So what will we say about its state? stateful? or still stateless?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will raise your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would make the textfield and radio buttons in one widget and make that one Statefull. If a radio button is beeing pressed call the setState() method.

Comment: Best way. Create your own StatefulWidget, then but in the build method the textfield and the radio buttons.